# Directive template - use attribute for html text interpolation?

Tags: angularjs

Angular 1.*

I  am using a directive to make my code drier... or attempting to. But because of variances in the json data structure, I am not sure it's possible because of the interpolation text for each radio button.

```
  <ppv-filter filter-name="Region" radio-value="choice.code" 
    sort="description" filter-data="regions"></ppv-filter>
  <ppv-filter filter-name="Market" display-prop="description"
    filter-data="markets"></ppv-filter>
  <ppv-filter filter-name="Dealer" display-prop="code"
    filter-data="dealers"></ppv-filter>
```

directive template:

```
  <div ng-if="filterName === 'Region'">
    <div ng-repeat="choice in filterData| orderBy: sort">
      <input type="radio" value="{{choice.code}}" name="regionRadio">
      {{choice.description}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="filterName === 'Market'">
    <div ng-repeat="choice in filterData| orderBy: 'code'">
      <input type="radio" name="bob">
      {{choice.code}}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="filterName === 'Dealer'">
    <div ng-repeat="choice in filterData| orderBy">
      <input type="radio" name="foo">
      {{choice}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('ppvFilter', ['regionMarketDealerSrv',
    function(regionMarketDealerSrv) {
      return {
        templateUrl: 'app/ppv/ppv-filter.dir.html',
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          filterName: '@',
          sort: '@',
          radioValue: '@',
          filterData: '='
        },
```

Is it possible to pass a attribute binding to take the place, for example, of `{{choice.description}}`? If not, then I am not really making my code drier by reusing a directive with so many code `ng-if` blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create controller inside Your directive and inside it check properties sended to scope, in this particular example best would be switch statement. So in the `switch` set which param should be used in view.

**( pseudo code in link or controller of directive )**

```
switch (scope.filterName){

  case "Market":
  scope.field="code";
  break;


  //other possibilities
}
```

Next in view we need only one structure by using array syntax **[field]**.

```
<div>
 <div ng-repeat="choice in filterData| orderBy: 'code'">
  <input type="radio" name="bob">
  {{choice[field]}}<!-- HERE MOST IMPORTANT -->
 </div>
</div>
```

I see that sorting also changes, so create second variable for sort type and assign it in the same `switch` in controller.

---

One more thing, directive attributes (props) assigned from parent scope can be used without any controller code, props are available in view, so it can be used in the same syntax like - `{{someArr[filterName]}}` where `filterName` was directive attribute.

Returning to Your problem - if we send by attribute name of property which should be used in view for example `column:'@'` and example value would be `code,description` then in view only `{{choice[column]}}` is needed.

Comment: Thanks. My goal is not to use a `switch` or `ng-if` ..... just use one single html block for the view of the directive. If not, I think the code would be easier to read without the directive with so many conditions.